# Is Possible Custom Select Field using ORM on Fuelphp?

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp

I have a problem when I want to query table using ORM ,example I have article table with field id,author,text.

My code like this :

```
// Single where
$article = Model_Article::find()->where('id', 4);
print_r($article);
```

that't code will be fetch all field on table article, it's like `select * from article where id = 4`

Try Possibility

```
$article = Model_Article::find(null, array('id','title'))->where('id', 3);
```

the response is

```
object(Orm\Query)#89 (14) {
  ["model":protected]=>
  string(10) "Model_Article"
  ["connection":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["view":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["alias":protected]=>
  string(2) "t0"
  ["relations":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["joins":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["select":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["t0_c0"]=>
    string(5) "t0.id"
  }
  ["limit":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["offset":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["rows_limit":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["rows_offset":protected]=>
  NULL
  ["where":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "and_where"
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "t0.id"
        [1]=>
        string(1) "="
        [2]=>
        int(3)
      }
    }
  }
  ["order_by":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["values":protected]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

that's is not return id or title field.

but when i'm try by adding get_one() method

```
$article = Model_Article::find(null, array('id','title'))->where('id', 3)->get_one();
```

id is return , but title is not and another field, i don't know why ?

**Reference**

1. [ORM Discussion FuelPHP](http://fuelphp.com/forums/topics/view/7076) it's say ORM currently will be select all column, no plans to change that at the moment.

**My Problem**

1. Select Custom Field using ORM like this `select id,owner from article where id = 4` it's will be return only id & owner, Is Possible to get that using ORM on FUELPHP ?

Comment: I'm not at home now, so try this and cross your finger ;-) : $article = Model_Article::find(null, array('id', 'owner'))->where('id', 4);
Reading the code of the framework this should work, let me know so I can write an answer for this.

Comment: i'm update my question after i'm try your suggestion...:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use

```
Model_Article::find()->
```

but use

```
Model_Article::query()->
```

The first one works but is considered an error situation which might change in future versions.

As of version 1.4 the ORM supports partial selects, using

```
Model::query()->select('id', 'value')->
```

The second parameter of find() is an array of conditions for the find, such as 'where' or 'order_by' clauses. There is no support for selecting column names in this array.

Answer (score 2):

The Orm\Model fetches all column because it can't deal with incomplete / partials objects.

If you want a custom query, don't use the ORM, use the query builder for that.

```
DB::select('id','title')->from(Model_Article::table())->where('id', 4);
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , i think so with your suggestion...:)

Comment: but that's still not fixing my problem, i'm prefer using Direct Query ,because i can customize my query...

Comment: The Query Builder has almost the same syntax as the Orm\Query class. You should be able to customise your query just the same.

Comment: I'm revision fuelphp has release new version and support select custom field using orm since version 1.4 ...

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to find out result like query "select * from article where id = 4"

```
$article = Model_Article::find()->where('id', 4)->get_one();

print_r($article);
```

and one more concept you should understand
get_one() returns only one record (as a object ).
get() returns multiple record ( in the form of array of objects ).

and if your field is not displaying then check the model Model_Article .this problem may be occur when you have not declared fields in properties list.

Answer (score 0):

Fuelphp has been release new version , you can see this documentation , in my case fuelphp version is 1.2 and cannot select custom field using orm.

select custom field using orm is available since version 1.4

http://fuelphp.com/docs/packages/orm/crud.html

```
// Find only some columns
Model_Article::query()->select('id', 'name');
Model_Article::find('all', array('select' => array('id', 'name')));
```